# Modify subsequent dropdown list with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html-lists

I have a web form with multiple dropdown lists. I would like to only display options in the second list that share the same value as the selection in the first list.

```
<!-- Dropdown #1 -->

<div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="select01">Select Tier</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <select id="select01">
                <option value="all">All Tiers</option>
                <option value="db">Database Tier</option>
                <option value="app">Application Tier</option>
                <option value="web">Web Tier</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>


<!-- Dropdown #2 -->

<div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="select01">Select Audit Point</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <select id="select03">
                <option value="all">Software Version</option>
                <option value="all">Server OS, Memory, CPU</option>
                <option value="all">High Availability</option>
                <option value="db">DBMS Version</option>
                <option value="db">DBMS Statistics</option>
                <option value="db">DBMS Parameters</option>
                <option value="db">DBMS Data File Growth</option>
                <option value="db">Database Disk Structure</option>
                <option value="db">Long Running SQL</option>
                <option value="db">Security Data Growth Range</option>
                <option value="db">Extraneous entries in System Tables</option>
                <option value="db">Feed Error Orphans</option>
                <option value="db">Position Detail Orphans</option>
                <option value="db">Data Retention Policy</option>
                <option value="db">Securities Added Daily</option>
                <option value="db">Security Master Load</option>
                <option value="db">SRM Purge</option>
                <option value="db">Best Pricing Purge</option>
                <option value="db">Partitioning</option>
                <option value="db">DBMS Data/Log File Utilize Shared Disk</option>
                <option value="db">DBMS Failover</option>
                <option value="app">DBMS Client Version</option>
                <option value="app">Star Engine IP Configuration</option>
                <option value="app">Engine Count/Configuration</option>
                <option value="app">STAR Engine Logging Interval</option>
                <option value="app">PACE Engine Port Configuration</option>
                <option value="app">PACE Server Logging</option>
                <option value="app">PACE Engine Log Configuration</option>
                <option value="app">STAR Engine Load Balancer Interval</option>
                <option value="app">Engines Restarted Weekly</option>
                <option value="app">Designated Master</option>
                <option value="app">Cluster Managers Identical</option>
                <option value="app">Uploader Shared Disk Space</option>
                <option value="app">Custom Archive Rule Shared Disk Space</option>
                <option value="app">App Server Clustering</option>
                <option value="app">PACE Event Concurrency</option>
                <option value="web">Homogenous Engine Configuration</option>
                <option value="web">Log Levels</option>
                <option value="web">Scheduler Purging</option>
                <option value="web">Web Server Services Restarted Weekly</option>
                <option value="web">Email Notification Basic Configuration</option>
                <option value="web"n>Web Load Balancer Configuration</option>
                <option value="web">Load Balancer Customizations</option>
                <option value="web">Portal Shared Disk Space</option>
                <option value="web">Message Center Shared Disk Space</option>
                <option value="web">Message Center ID'S</option>
                <option value="web">Schedule Service Config</option>
                <option value="web">ePace is a client of Clustered App Servers</option>
                <option value="web">Portal is a client of Clustered App Servers</option>
                <option value="web">ESTAR is a client of Clustered Load Balancers</option>
                <option value="web">ESTAR is a client of Clustered Engines</option>
                <option value="web">ESTAR is a client of Clustered Report Export Services</option>
                <option value="web">WebSync Configured</option>
                <option value="web">Web Server Load Balancing Configured</option>
                <option value="web">Shared Disk Dynamic Folder</option>
```

I need to be able to continuously change the list 1 selection, so I cannot .remove() unmatched options in the 2nd list. If I did remove them, I would then need to re-populate the 2nd list on each new selection from the 1st list.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you make multiple dropdowns and only show the appropriate one based on selection instead? You might also want to look into [optgroup](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested with your HTML-Code and works properly... You only have to modify this code so that there will be a filtered selection when loading the page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var savedOptions = '';

    savedOptions = jQuery('#select03').html(); //save the second dropdown-list

    jQuery('#select01').change(function() {
        var selectedValue = jQuery('#select01').val(); //After changing the value of the first dropdown, store this value inside a variable

        jQuery('#select03').html(savedOptions); //restore the content of the 2nd dropdown
        jQuery('#select03').children('option').each(function() {
            if(jQuery(this).attr('value') != selectedValue) {
                jQuery(this).remove(); //Compare and step through the 2nd dropdown and delete all unneccessary options
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot have duplicated option values inside the select** element.

It is better you have a separate element that holds the options tag. And then replace the `value` with `data-value` attributes.

Try this

```
$('#select01').on('change', function() {

    var $select03 = $('#select03'),
        currValue = this.value;

    $select03.empty();

    var $options = $('.template option').filter(function() {
          return $(this).data('value') === currValue  
    }).get();

    $select03.append($options);
}).change();
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dUGrH/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the options like so:

```
$("#select01").change(function() {
    //Get value from the selected option
    var filter = this.value;

    //Loop thru second select options
    $("#select02 option").each(function() {
        //Enable the option (used for if the select changes values)
        $(this).prop("disabled", false);

        //Compare second select values to the initial selected value
        if (this.value != filter) {

            //Disable options that do not match
            $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QXhRy/

I suppose you could also completely remove the options as well, however, this would involve re-building the `select` each time you change the initial dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Create a "map" of String arrays and populate from this as needed.

```
// initialize options on page load
var options = new Array();
options["all"] = new Array("A","B","C");
options["db"] = new Array("D","E","F");

function changeSecondDropDown(selectedValue)
{
  // clear options from second drop down list
  ...

  var optionsToAdd = options[selectedValue]
  // loop through options and add them to second drop down list
  ...
}
```